# VS Code Remote SSH

Tags: ssh, vscode-remote-ssh

I installed the Microsoft Remote - SSH extension and I am unable to SSH to an Ubuntu computer. I can SSH to the computer via putty no problem so I know it can do it. After selecting the extension in the bottom left corner, I select Connect to host and enter username@10.1.2.5. I'm then prompted to choose Linux, Windows or macOS and after I select Linux I receive the following error:

**An SSH installation couldn't be found.**

It doesn't matter what OS I select, they all give the same error. Below is the SSH client and server installed on the computer.

**openssh-client**/focal-updates,now 1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
**openssh-server**/focal-updates,now 1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.4 amd64 [installed]

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you on Windows/Linux and forget to install a supported SSH client? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_installing-a-supported-ssh-client

Comment: Hi Lex Li, I am using Linux and installed the following that is supported. openssh-client/focal-updates,now 1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
openssh-server/focal-updates,now 1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.4 amd64 [installed]

Comment: You have two machines (host and guest) if you want to use VSCode Remote, so both of them are Ubuntu with openssh-client installed? You referred to putty, so I think the host is a Windows machine and you don't have Windows OpenSSH Client installed.

Comment: Found my pc is running version 1609, not 1809, that's the issue. Thank you for your help.